# I have designed a custom style in blend and want to use it in my code in c# . How to achieve it?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have created a custom button for my application in blend and used its resource in my xaml code.
But i want to use it in my class xyztextbutton.
But unable to o so as.

**[ button.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["ButtonStyle1"];]**
 is not working properly

And I am adding it to a layout-root later on but still not working.

phone:PhoneApplicationPage

```
x:Class="xyz.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"    
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit">

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF216391" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="path" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF3E8EBB" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="path" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Path x:Name="path" Data="M22.729,0 L22.73,0 L107.729,0 L107.729,38 L22.76,38 L22.76,38.031 L-0.483128,19.5199 L22.729,0.000793 z" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" Stroke="#FFD0E21D" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="#FF5FB4E4" Margin="-0.483,0,0,0"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="24,1,4,9" Width="80" Height="30" OpacityMask="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Height="800">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>-->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

```
public class xyzTextButton

{

    private int ScreenWidth = Convert.ToInt32(Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth);
    private int ScreenHeight = Convert.ToInt32(Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight);
    Grid uiGrid = null;
    Image image = null;
    TextBlock textblock = null;
    Button button = null;
    Dictionary<string, object> actions = null;

    public void CreateTextButton(Dictionary<string, object> dict, Grid grid, string pagename)

    {

        uiGrid = new Grid();
        image = new Image();
        button = new Button();
        button.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["ButtonStyle1"];
        textblock = new TextBlock();
        Boolean autoresizesSubviews = Convert.ToBoolean(ObjectForKey("autoresizesSubviews", dict));
        actions = (Dictionary<string, object>)ObjectForKey("actions", dict);

     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know it should work.

Ok, how about changing the whole method?

How about developing Custom User Control, just copy-paste your XAML, name it MyButton, and use as a ordinary button:

MyButton a = new MyButton();